# C# Try Catch Statement Query

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a question about Try Catch statements in C#.

For example if I had a statement as such

```
try
{
    string text = sometext;
    var Auto_IMPORT = new AutoImport();
    Auto_IMPORT.StartProcessing();
    Console.WriteLine(sometext);
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
    //Would this catch AutoImport.StartProcessing() exceptions?
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

AutoImport is a Class Library and i'm calling some logic to start processing.
If an exception occurred within the logic inside AutoImport.StartProcessing() would this try statement catch that exception or would it be out of scope by then?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I think, it would. It catches any exception occurring in try block.

Comment: if exception occurs in same thread then yes.

Comment: This question is out of scope as is, since we do not know how your 3rd party library is built. You would need to contact the company who supplies such a DLL. That being said, frameworks do tend to throw their own custom exceptions should something break, but this is by no means a standard.

Comment: The class library is our own and in-house written. The class library is just a method to move some files around.

Comment: Then in that case I'd recommend you go through the source and see what sort of exception handling does the code provide.

Comment: Based upon the name I'd tend to think the operation `StartProcessing` is asynchronous. If that is the case and the asynchronous operation is executed in its own thread then you won't catch the exception.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the behavior of `Auto_IMPORT.StartProcessing()`. If no exception is caught in it, then yes, you will get an exception. On the other hand, if the internal code off `Auto_IMPORT` catches the exception, and doesn't throw a new exception, then you wont get any exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
It catches any errors that are in the `try` block. Doesn't matter if they're in some method of some class.

Tested with:

```
class _Class
    {
        public string name;
        public void myMethod()
        {
            int i;
            string s = "asda";
            i = int.Parse(s);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _Class blah = new _Class();
                blah.name = "Steve";
                blah.myMethod();
            }
           catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Caught exception at int.Parse